# MongoDB _id query on capped collection without an _id index, performance will be poor collection

Tags: c#, mongodb

i create a capped collection(`crawl02`) and create an index for this capped.

```
> db.system.indexes.find()
{ "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "ns" : "test.crawl02", "name" : "_id_" }
```

when i runing an application and query capped collection,the `MongoDB Log` ALWAYS output the follow log:

`[conn2] warning: _id query on capped collection without an _id index, performance will be poor collection: test.crawl02`.

my code statement to query a capped collection (c#)

```
 var cursor = this.QueueCollection    //crawl02
           .Find(Query.GT("_id", this._lastId))
           .SetFlags(QueryFlags.AwaitData |QueryFlags.TailableCursor 
                    | QueryFlags.NoCursorTimeout)
           .SetSortOrder(SortBy.Ascending("$natural"));
 return (MongoCursorEnumerator<QueueMessage<T>>)cursor.GetEnumerator();
```

read a message from about cursor variable:

```
while(true){
   if (this._cursor.MoveNext())
      return this._currsor.Current;
   else
      return null
}
```

i don't understand why the mongodb waning me the `crawl02` not have an index.

====================================
by update

ok,i found an article about Tailable Cursors at [MongoDB office website](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Tailable+Cursors),the message is :

`Tailable cursors are only allowed on capped collections and can only return objects in natural order. Tailable queries never use indexes.`

that's because mongodb log warning? `Tailable queries never use indexes.??`

===================update 2
sorry,i forgot the mongodb log warning is about test.crawl02,i has changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says you have no index on test.crawl01. This is correct. When you you do 
`db.system.indexes.find()` 
you have an index on the _id field on test.crawl02 not test.crawl01
Create an index on test.crawl01.

Comment: sorry,i changed my post.it's about test.crawl02,i forgot change.